# Checking if a QImage has an alpha channel

Tags: qt

I want to know if a `QImage` I loaded contains an alpha channel. I already know that `QImage::hasAlphaChannel()` can tell me if the image format I'm using supports alpha channels, but is there a way to know if it's actually being used in the loaded image?

Comment: What do you mean by "used"? Having at least one pixel with alpha different from opaque?

Comment: @vines Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you have my snippet for checking if alpha is really used. It's useful when image is in [ARGB32](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qimage.html#Format-enum).

```
bool useAlpha = false;
const uchar* pixelData = image.bits();
int bytes = image.byteCount();

for (const QRgb* pixel = reinterpret_cast<const QRgb*>(pixelData); bytes > 0; pixel++, bytes -= sizeof(QRgb)) {
    if (qAlpha(*pixel) != UCHAR_MAX) {
        useAlpha = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Remember also that there is [format()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qimage.html#format) method.

Comment: I've read that you should use `static_cast` instead of `reinterpret_cast` whenever possible. My compiler won't let me use `static_cast` in this context. Could you explain what `reinterpret_cast` is used for in this case and why `static_cast` doesn't work?

Comment: @Pieter [QRgb](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qcolor.html#QRgb-typedef) (`unsigned int`) is different type than uchar (`unsigned char`), thus pointers are incompatible. `static_cast` is useful only for related types (like class and its subclass). Check: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/. [bits()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qimage.html#bits) returns pointer to the first pixel data, and as I said before I assume that image is in 32bpp format, so casting to QRgb* is safe and actually required, as [scanline()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qimage.html#scanLine) description explains.

Answer (score 1):

If the format you load the `QImage` as has an alpha channel, your `QImage` has an alpha channel.

If you're checking to see if any pixel in an image with an alpha channel actually sets any pixel to something other than opaque, you could try something like generating an alpha mask using `QImage::createAlphaMask()` and inspecting its pixel values.

Comment: [createAlphaMask()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qimage.html#createAlphaMask) adds not justified here overhead. IOW: There is no reason to create another QImage just to check its content, because you can do it in original image. What's important, such image from this method is 1bpp, so there is loss of information.