# How can I find out if a `QPixmap` has transparency?

Tags: image, qt, transparency, qpixmap

I have some `QGraphicsPixmapItem` that will contain images...  of any kind.

I will have to perform certain processing, that is very simple if the image contained in the item is fully opaque, but more complicated if there is transparency. So I want to separate these 2 situations.

How can I find out if a `QGraphicsPixmapItem` or a `QPixmap` has transparency ?

(the only thing I found so far is [QPixmap::mask()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#mask):

> Extracts a bitmap mask from the pixmap's alpha channel.
>   Warning: This is potentially an expensive operation. The mask of the pixmap is extracted dynamically from the pixeldata.

not sure what i do with it...
or I can iterate myself through pixel data till I find a pixel with some transparency... either version seems ineffective)

Update:

After implementing it myself, I found an older similar question:
[Checking if a QImage has an alpha channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157286/checking-if-a-qimage-has-an-alpha-channel)

(seems nobody else found an alternative to iterating through all pixel data)

Comment: You can find out about specific pixel and not the whole QPixmap.

Comment: will this work for you? - http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#hasAlpha

Comment: hasAlpha can return true although the image is fully opaque. It just means that the image would support transparency, not that there is necessarily any. I think one would have to convert to QImage and iterate over the pixels, which is expensive (both the conversion to QImage and the iteration). One could do it upfront though and store the result, then it might be doable.

Comment: how do you load the images? Is that processing complexity more than linear in the number of pixels?

Comment: My loading: get the file name  then call, in my object (child of `QGraphicsPixmapItem`): `QPixmap p(filename);` `setPixmap(p);`

Comment: The processing complexity ... (1) it can be done many times over the lifetime of the object (though I could determine transparency at first time then cache it); IF the image contains transparency, instead of processing the image I would have to obtain a different clipping, much larger than the image, and perform a lengthy processing of that. So I was hoping there was an easy way... Something already implemented maybe.